# How to download influxdb2.0 data in csv format?

Tags: influxdb, influxdb-2, flux-influxdb

I am not familiar with influxdb command line especially influxDB2.0. so I choose to use InfluxDB 8086 port frontend. but I found if want to download .csv by frontend, too many data leads to browser collapse, which at last leads to download failure.

I have read influxdb2.0 documentation and found no answer. Whether I must use command line or what command line should I use? Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issues using Flux in a browser session.

If you need a lot of data use the [Influx API](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.0/query-data/execute-queries/influx-api/) and catch the result in a file. See the 'example query request' using curl on the referenced page. I find this to be very quick and haven't had it overload from returning large data sets.

(If the amount of data is enormous you can also ask Influx to gzip it before download, but of course this may load up the machine it's running on.)